# Spring Boot actuator healthcheck not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot 2.3.8 here. My `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 9200
  error:
    whitelabel:
      enabled: false
  ssl:
    enabled: false
spring:
  cache:
    type: none
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://${db.hostAndPort}/${db.name}?useSSL=false&nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: ${db.username}
    password: ${db.password}
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL5InnoDBSpatialDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
management:
  port: 9200
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: prometheus
```

I then wrote my own custom `HealthIndicator` impl:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyAppHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() {
        Health.Builder health = Health.up();
        return health.build();
    }

}
```

When I run my app, it starts up just fine. But when I go to run a curl against the health check endpoint:

```
$ curl -k -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:9200/actuator/health
HTTP/1.1 404 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 31 Jan 2021 01:30:39 GMT

{"timestamp":"2021-01-31T01:30:39.206+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/actuator/health"}
```

Have I forgotten a step? Do I need to add anything? Anything wrong with my YAML file? Why can't it find my health check url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom MyAppHealthIndicator class as Spring Boot comes with a default health indicator which is actived by default via the Endoint /actuator/health/

You're problem is the application.yml configuration where you define that you only want to expose the prometheus endpoint. But you should enable also the health endpoint:

```
...
endpoints:
  web:
    exposure:
      include: health, prometheus
...
```

Now you can access it via: http://localhost:9200/actuator/health/

For more details see the offical docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints

Comment: That's awesome, thanks @Oliver (+1). Suppose I **do** want a custom health indicator like I wrote above. Anything else I need to add to my configuration, or does your answer cover custom indicators as well? Thanks again!

Comment: This covers all custom indicators health indicators as well (as the endpoint is the same)